# How can I print list of users data by for loop stored in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Datas are stored in this format.

```
$user1 = array('shaon53',78,'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:33:26 PM');
$user2 = array('samiulbasir',50, 'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:34:28 PM');
$user3 = array('sabbir25',210, 'PM ', 'Jan-21-2015 18:35:25 PM');
$user4 = array('jon05',40, 'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:36:21 PM');
$user5 = array('mishu',52, 'PM ', 'Jan-21-2015 18:37:20 PM');
```

I want to create a table where each column of the row will hold data of single array like below.

```
<table>
 for ($i = 1; $i < 304; $i++) {

        echo '<tr> <td >';

        echo $user1[3];

        echo '</td ><td > ';
        echo $user1[0];

        echo '</td ><td > ';

        echo $user1[1];

        echo '</td ><td > ';

        echo $user1[2];
        echo '</td ></tr>';

    }
    </table>
```

So the second line when i =2 will print

```
<tr>
    <td>user2[3]</td>
    <td>user2[0]</td>
    <td>user2[1]</td>
    <td>user2[2]</td>
</tr>
```

Third line of the table will show 'user3' datas.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use `${"user$i"}` instead of `$user1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user1 = array('shaon53',78,'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:33:26 PM');
$user2 = array('samiulbasir',50, 'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:34:28 PM');
$user3 = array('sabbir25',210, 'PM ', 'Jan-21-2015 18:35:25 PM');
$user4 = array('jon05',40, 'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:36:21 PM');
$user5 = array('mishu',52, 'PM ', 'Jan-21-2015 18:37:20 PM');

echo "<table>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { // Up to number of users:
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach(${"user".$i} as $a){
        echo "<td>".$a."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have shown you how with [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but the better solution would be to use an array of arrays:

```
$user[1] = array('shaon53',78,'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:33:26 PM');
$user[2] = array('samiulbasir',50, 'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:34:28 PM');

//or (starts at 0)
$user[] = array('shaon53',78,'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:33:26 PM');
$user[] = array('samiulbasir',50, 'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:34:28 PM');
```

Then use `$i` as the first level of the array:

```
echo $user[$i][3];
```

Or use a `foreach`:

```
foreach($user as $value) {
    echo $value[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really into the $user1,$user2,$user3 format?
I would suggest that you put all those users into one big array to make it easy to sort/search/etc

```
$alluserarray=array();

$alluserarray[]= array('shaon53',78,'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:33:26 PM');
$alluserarray[] = array('samiulbasir',50, 'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:34:28 PM');
$alluserarray[] = array('sabbir25',210, 'PM ', 'Jan-21-2015 18:35:25 PM');
$alluserarray[] = array('jon05',40, 'PM', 'Jan-21-2015 18:36:21 PM');
$alluserarray[] = array('mishu',52, 'PM ', 'Jan-21-2015 18:37:20 PM');

foreach($alluserarray as $oneuser){
    echo '<tr> <td >';
    echo $oneuser[3];
    echo '</td ><td > ';
    echo $oneuser[0];
    echo '</td ><td > ';
    echo $oneuser[1];
    echo '</td ><td > ';
    echo $oneuser[2];
    echo '</td ></tr>';
}
```